# ngClass boolean expression gets a template parsing error

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, angular7

I want to check if a **moment** date is the current day. This isn't working and I'm not sure why it's getting this error. I think the error because of Angular.

```
<div class="timeline-date"
      *ngFor="let date of dates"
      [ngClass]="{'current-date': date.isSame(new Date(), 'day') }">
  {{date.format("MMM Do")}}
</div>
```

Error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Missing expected
>   ) at column 34 in [{'current-date': date.isSame(new Date(), 'day') }]

Comment: Its supposed to be [ngClass]="{'current-date' ? date.isSame(new Date(): 'day') }">

Comment: @ThanveerShah this is not a valid syntax for ngClass.

Comment: That's how you do ternary operation

Comment: @ThanveerShah Yes, but why are you talking about ternary here ? This has nothing to do with ternary.

Comment: I think the problem is about `new Date()` afaik you cannot call `new` in template. Can you try to make `isSame()` a method that returns `boolean` in the component and pass variables to it? Or, you can define a property like `newDate = new Date()` and use it in `date.isSame()`, maybe.

Comment: To me, the problem is with `new Date()`.
The best option would be map dates. Add new property isSame which will hold the result of the method and in template use it like `[ngClass]="{'current-date': date.isSame}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be cause of the `isSame` method.
Declare a boolean var, which will be the result of this method:

```
isSame: boolean;
// ...
isDateSame = date.isSame(new Date(), 'day');
```

And use the boolean in the `ngClass`:

```
<div class="timeline-date"
    *ngFor="let date of dates"
    [ngClass]="current-date: isSame">
  {{date.format("MMM Do")}}
</div>
```

**EDIT**: How to properly use `moment.js` with angular:

1. Install it with `npm`

   `npm install --save moment`
2. Import it in the `.ts` file:

   `import * as moment from 'moment';`
3. Use it like that:

   `let myMoment: moment.Moment = moment("someDate");`